# How to use tidy evaluation with a non-tidyverse package

Tags: r, functional-programming, tidyverse, survey, tidyeval

I am trying to develop a function which will calculate the means, standard error, and confidence intervals of some survey data. I need to do this repeatedly over a number of different variables with a bunch of different filter statements.

**DATA**

```
df  <-  data.frame(address_id = rep(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),5),
                   person_id = rep(c(1,2,3),20),
                   sex = as.factor(rep(c("male","female"),30)),
                   response_var = as.factor(rep(seq(1,6,1))),
                   weight = runif(60, 50, 200))
```

**Example that works without function**

```
# create survey design
design <- survey::svydesign(data = df, 
                              strata = ~ address_id, 
                              id = ~ person_id,
                              nest = TRUE, 
                              weights = ~ weight)

# calcualte weighted mean 
mean_se <- survey::svymean(~sex, design)

# calculate confidence intervals 
ci <- survey::confint(df_mean)
```

**My function**

```
create_mean_and_cis <- function(data, var){

design <- survey::svydesign(data = data, 
                            strata = ~ address_id, 
                            id = ~ person_id,
                            nest = TRUE, 
                            weights = ~ weight)

 mean_se <- survey::svymean(~{{var}}, design)
 
 ci <- confint(mean_se)%>%
   tibble::as_tibble()%>%
   tibble::rownames_to_column("variable")
 
 output <- mean_se%>%
   tibble::as_tibble()%>%
   tibble::rownames_to_column("variable")%>%
   dplyr::left_join(ci)

return(output)
}

# function call
create_mean_and_cis(sex)
```

When I run, I get an error message saying:

```
Error in survey::svydesign(data = data, strata = ~address_id, id = ~person_id,  : 
  object 'sex' not found
```

I can't understand what is going wrong. The tidy evaluation works perfectly when I use the curly-curly "{{var}}" within other functions. Why doesn't it work here? Can anyone help?

I have tried several variations of quasiquotation including: !!enquo(sex), sym(sex), !!sym(sex), {{sex}}, eval(parse(sex)). None of which have yielded working results.

Comment: Another approach is to use the tidyversatile `srvyr` package, which wraps `survey`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to use more advanced tidy evaulation features, you can use `rlang::eval_tidy`

```
mean_se <- rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::quo(survey::svymean(~{{var}}, design)))
```

You wrap your expression in a quosure where you can use the `{{ }}` and `!!` style syntax. Both `quo` and `eval_tidy` will recognize this syntax. These features are unique to functions that use the `rlang` package; you cannot use them directly any arbitrary R function without some sort of `rlang` wrapper.

Or per @Lionel's suggestion, you can use `rlang::inject` to build the formula and pass that to `svymean`

```
formula <- rlang::inject(~!!substitute(var))
mean_se <- survey::svymean(formula, design)
```

Comment: You can also inject into a formula with `inject()` but should make sure never to inject a quosure, only bare expressions. Then the formula can be used in base functions.

Comment: @LionelHenry I've updated the post with what I think you were suggesting. If that's not right, let me know.

Comment: oh I meant `inject(~ !!substitute(var))`. The `{{` syntax creates a quosure which is only compatible in tidyverse NSE functions.

Answer (score 4):

The actual error you are getting is because you aren't passing the `data` argument to `create_mean_and_cis` ( you are doing `create_mean_and_cis(sex)` whereas it should be `create_mean_and_cis(df, sex)`).

However, this will not on its own fix the problem, since the curly-curly operator won't work inside a formula. Instead, you need to do something like:

```r
create_mean_and_cis <- function(data, var){
  
  var <- deparse(substitute(var))
  design <- survey::svydesign(data = data, 
                              strata = ~ address_id, 
                              id = ~ person_id,
                              nest = TRUE, 
                              weights = ~ weight)
  
  mean_se <- survey::svymean(as.formula(paste('~', var)), design)
  
  ci <- confint(mean_se)%>%
    tibble::as_tibble()%>%
    tibble::rownames_to_column("variable")
  
  output <- mean_se%>%
    tibble::as_tibble()%>%
    tibble::rownames_to_column("variable")%>%
    dplyr::left_join(ci)
  
  return(output)
}
```

Which allows

```r
create_mean_and_cis(df, sex)
#Joining, by = "variable"
## A tibble: 2 x 5
#   variable  mean    SE `2.5 %` `97.5 %`
#   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#  1 1        0.481 0.163   0.161    0.802
#  2 2        0.519 0.163   0.198    0.839
```

Comment: Instead of `paste("~", var)` could try `reformulate(var)` ,